# Números primos en java

Tags: java, bucles, booleano

Estoy intentado hacer un programa que me muestre por pantalla si los números (5 números introducidos por teclado) son primos o no. He conseguido hacer este código pero cuando ejecuto cualquier numero que ponga siempre me pone que es primo, cuando realmente alguno de ellos no son primos. Creo que tiene algo que ver con el *boolean* ya que si lo igualo a true me sale que es primo y cuando lo igualo a false me sale que no es primo.

Espero que me podáis ayudar un poco. Gracias.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num = 0;
    boolean primo;
    while (num<5){
        System.out.println("Ingrese un numero");
         num= sc.nextInt();
         if(num<2){
            System.out.println("El numero "+num+ " es primo");
        }else{
            System.out.println("El numero "+num+ " no es primo");
        }
        primo(num);
    }
}

private static boolean primo(int num) {
    boolean prim = true;
     
    int divisor=2;
     
    while((prim) && (divisor!=num)){
        if((num%divisor==0)){
            prim=false;
        }else{
            divisor++;
        }
    }
    return prim;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te está pasando es que, primero sacas por pantalla el mensaje de si es primo o no (que siempre devuelve que lo es porque el if siempre se cumple por tus restricciones previas) y luego compruebas si lo es.

Te arreglo el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
   int num = 0;
   boolean esPrimo;
   while (num<5){
   System.out.println("Ingrese un numero");
   num= sc.nextInt();
   esPrimo = primo(num)
    if(esPrimo){
       System.out.println("El numero "+num+ " es primo");
    }else{
        System.out.println("El numero "+num+ " no es primo");
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

```
private static boolean primo(int num) {
 boolean prim = true;
 
 int divisor=2;
 
 while((prim) && (divisor!=num)){
     if((num%divisor==0)){
         prim=false;
     }else{
         divisor++;
     }
 }
    return prim;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Sergio, me da ahora un pequeño error en el private static boolean primo. ¿Por qué crees que sería este error? (SOLUCIONADO)